# How does the observable work inside the Redux library source code?

Tags: javascript, redux, observable

When I went through the source of the Redux library I noticed a funny weird syntax:

```
[$$observable]() {
        return this
}
```

I looked at it and I checked the TC39 proposal but I can't wrap my head around it. How is this 'consumed'? Does it 'emit' something? I don't understand it all. What does this observable do in the context of Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Symbol.observable` is intended to be a universal indication that an object can be treated as an observable.  Redux uses the `symbol-observable` polyfill package to mark itself as observable, so that you could do something like `Observable.from(store)` (or whatever the actual syntax is).